# Join two views with a line

Tags: android, canvas, graph

I have all the elements(text as well as image views) that I want to show in place, all I need to do now is show a line joining some of my views(I am trying to generate a connection graph look).Is there any other way to do this without using canvas? Another doubt that I have is, if I go for a custom view using canvas can I use other Image/Textviews as it is along with canvas in the same activity?

I'm new to android, that's why confused, please show me some direction to move in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  to create a blank view. Add width and other properties to it to make it visible as a line.

```
<View android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</LinearLayout>
 <View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</LinearLayout>
```

**View** tag seperated two layouts like small line

Answer (score 0):

I have done same with `CustomView`. Have a look:

[image: Connectors]

CustomView Class Source Code:

```
public class CustomView extends View
{
    Paint            paint     = new Paint();
    float            startingX, startingY, endingX, endingY;

    ArrayList<Lines> line_list = new ArrayList<Lines>();     ;

    boolean flag = false;
    boolean flag1 = false;
    public class Lines
    {
        float startingX, startingY, endingX, endingY;
    }
    Context context;
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context=context;
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setNumberOfLine(int x )
    {
        line_list = new ArrayList<Lines>(); 
        int y = getHeight();
        int z = getWidth();
        System.out.println("length  => "+x);
        System.out.println("height  => "+y);
        System.out.println("width   => "+z);

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            Lines l = new Lines();
            l.startingX = z / 2;
            l.startingY = 0;
            l.endingX = i*(z/x)+(z/(x*2));
            l.endingY = y;
            System.out.println("l.endingX   => " + l.endingX);
            System.out.println("l.endingY   => " + l.endingY);
            line_list.add(l);
        }
        flag = true;
        flag1 = false;
        invalidate();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setNumberOfLine1(int x , int position , int total , float getX)
    {
        line_list = new ArrayList<Lines>(); 
        int y = getHeight();
//      Display display = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
//      int z = display.getWidth();
        int z;

        float start=0;
//      
        if(x<5)
        {
            Display display = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            z = display.getWidth();
            start = position*(z/total)+(z/(total*2));
        }
        else
        {
            z = getWidth();
            start = getX;
        }

        System.out.println("length  => "+x);
        System.out.println("height  => "+y);
        System.out.println("width   => "+z);

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            Lines l = new Lines();
            if(x==1)
            {
                l.startingX = start;
                l.startingY = 0;
                l.endingX = 2*(z/total)+(z/(total*2));
                l.endingY = y;
            }
            else if(x==2)
            {
                if(i==0)
                {
                    l.startingX = start;
                    l.startingY = 0;
                    l.endingX = 1*(z/total)+(z/(total*2));
                    l.endingY = y;
                }
                else if(i==1)
                {
                    l.startingX = start;
                    l.startingY = 0;
                    l.endingX = 3*(z/total)+(z/(total*2));
                    l.endingY = y;
                }

            }
            else if(x==3)
            {
                if(i==0)
                {
                    l.startingX = start;
                    l.startingY = 0;
                    l.endingX = 2*(z/total)+(z/(total*2));
                    l.endingY = y;
                }
                else if(i==2)
                {
                    l.startingX = start;
                    l.startingY = 0;
                    l.endingX = 3*(z/total)+(z/(total*2));
                    l.endingY = y;
                }
                else if(i==3)
                {
                    l.startingX = start;
                    l.startingY = 0;
                    l.endingX = 4*(z/total)+(z/(total*2));
                    l.endingY = y;
                }

            }
            else if(x==4)
            {
                if(i==0)
                {
                    l.startingX = start;
                    l.startingY = 0;
                    l.endingX = 1*(z/total)+(z/(total*2));
                    l.endingY = y;
                }
                else if(i==2)
                {
                    l.startingX = start;
                    l.startingY = 0;
                    l.endingX = 2*(z/total)+(z/(total*2));
                    l.endingY = y;
                }
                else if(i==3)
                {
                    l.startingX = start;
                    l.startingY = 0;
                    l.endingX = 3*(z/total)+(z/(total*2));
                    l.endingY = y;
                }
                else if(i==3)
                {
                    l.startingX = start;
                    l.startingY = 0;
                    l.endingX = 5*(z/total)+(z/(total*2));
                    l.endingY = y;
                }

            }
            else 
            {
//              l.startingX = start;
//              l.startingY = 0;
//              l.endingX = i*(z/total)+(z/(total*2));
//              l.endingY = y;
                l.startingX = start;
                l.startingY = 0;
                l.endingX = i*(z/x)+(z/(x*2));
                l.endingY = y;
            }
            line_list.add(l);   
            System.out.println("l.endingX   1=> " + l.endingX);
            System.out.println("l.endingY   1=> " + l.endingY);
        }
        flag1 = true;
        flag = false;
        invalidate();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple_dark));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(Utility.dpToPx(5, context));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is that `CustomView`? You should provide more details to support your answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, can you direct me to a tutorial or article that helps

Comment: @SainiAnkit I have updated my answer with `CustomView` source code.